# SwiftUI setting Object Variables within ForEach is not working

Tags: swiftui

I have a scrolling view that displays an Object's Name as a Text View within a ForEach, I also have a GeometryReader because I need to know the position of each Object within the ScrollView. When displaying the Text View I have a function *showObject()* set the object's number to be it's position according to the GeometryReader.

So here's my problem. Above the ScrollView I have 3 Texts that show the name and number of the Objects for debug purposes. When scrolling, object[0]'s number updates like I expect it to, but object[1] and object[2] stay at the initialized 100 value. I have a print set up in my *showObject()* function and it's receiving the correct information, however it appears that it's failing to set the number on my objects after object[0]. Does anyone know why this is happening? Or perhaps a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

```
struct MyObject {
    var name:String
    var number:CGFloat = 100
}


struct MyScrollView: View {

    @State var objects: [MyObject] = [MyObject(name: "a"), MyObject(name: "b"), MyObject(name: "c")]

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Text(objects[0].name + " --- " + (objects[0].number.description))
            Text(objects[1].name + " --- " + (objects[1].number.description))
            Text(objects[2].name + " --- " + (objects[2].number.description))

                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){

                    VStack{

                        ForEach(self.options.indices) { i in

                            GeometryReader {geo in

                                self.showObject(index: i, num: geo.frame(in: .global).minY)

                            } // geo

                        } // ForEach

                    } // VStack inside ScrollView

                } // ScrollView

        } // top vstack

    } // body


    func showObject(index: Int, num: CGFloat) -> Text
    {
        objects[index].number = num


        print (objects[index].name + " -- should be: " + num.description + " -- actual: " + objects[index].number.description)
        return Text(objects[index].name)
    }

} // view
```

Comment: Hi @Kabir, did you find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Any change in `@State var objects` result in your `MyScrollView` redraw, ie recreation. So, rendering engine starts drawing your `MyScrollView`, comes to `objects[index].number = num`, which modifies `@State var objects` that reports that new redraw needed...

```
a -- should be: 94.0 -- actual: 100.0
2019-11-22 08:14:11.535085+0200 Testing[73866:816126] [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

... rendering interrupted and goes from start. This is why you observed only 1st `MyObject` changes.

Solution... well, you need to place `.number` out of workflow affecting recursive redraw. The simplest is defer modifications to next event cycle, like

```
if self.objects[index].number != num { // avoid redraw for same values
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.objects[index].number = num
    }
}
```

However, in general it is better to put `MyModel` outside of view and make some ViewModel wrapper, which would have view-effecting published `name` but not `number`, but this depends on your real needs.